# vue3-easy-data-table not working with js (without typescript)

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

vue3-easy-data-table not working/rendring table in a vue3 cli project with JavaScript 
While googling all example are with typescript, didn't found any working example with js **(without typescript)**.

**warning console**
[image]

**Regist**

```
const instance = createApp(App);
instance.component("EasyDataTable", Vue3EasyDataTable);
instance.mount("#app");
```

**Template**

```
<template>
  <EasyDataTable
   :headers="headers"
   :items="items"
  />
</template>
```

**js**

```
data: ()=> ({
      headers:[
          { text: "Name", value: "name" },
          { text: "Height (cm)", value: "height", sortable: true },
          { text: "Weight (kg)", value: "weight", sortable: true },
          { text: "Age", value: "age", sortable: true }
        ],
        items: [
          { "name": "Curry", "height": 178, "weight": 77, "age": 20 },
          { "name": "James", "height": 180, "weight": 75, "age": 21 },
          { "name": "Jordan", "height": 181, "weight": 73, "age": 22 }
        ],
  })
```

Am I missing anything?
any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the complete code of your .vue file